# Android send SMS without User Interface. Asking about cost to mobile account

Tags: android, sms

I want to send SMS with out user interface. for that i have done this.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager
                            .sendTextMessage("#####", null, "COM", null, null);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

In Manifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

working good but says

```
this could cause costs to your mobile account
```

I really don't want this user interfere.how to solve this?
is it really possible or not?
 Please help me to solve this problem,..

Thanks,

Comment: This can cost money from mobile operator. This is the warning of that permission.

Comment: it asks user to deduct money or not i want to remove this. is it possible?

Comment: you can not remove permission, otherwise application crashed. For sending SMS you compulsory add that permission to manifest. It doesn't prompt user to sms dialog. Directly sends sms via mobile operator. So operator deduct money for that

Comment: i mean to say. when user sending sms to 3#### number. then at sending SMS time it says it will charge and will deduct money and user asked for allow decut money or can select No option i want to remove this

Comment: I don't know for sure but I think it is impossible without a custom ROM.  What you're asking for is basically the ability to charge money to the user's mobile account without their approval.  I'm sure you can see why that's problematic and why the system will not allow it.

Comment: Also when you are quoting please make sure it is RIGHT... "may cause charges"

Answer (score 1):

For obvious reason, you shouldn't try to deduct money from a user's account without their approval as this will reflect poorly on your app and company and will get flagged and likely removed from the google play store.

Looking at the dev docs @

[Dev Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Looking at the code @

http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/SMSDispatcher.java#292

Looks like this is coming from the telephony stack, so no you **CANNOT** seem to bypass it unless your has has been marked to always allow.

Comment: no i am not going to upload this app i market. i just want to give this app to hand to hand

Comment: please send me link again it's not opening

Comment: can you please explain it. your answer Looks like this is coming from the telephony stack, so no you can't seem to bypass it unless your has has been marked to always allow. it is not undersable

Comment: can you plz explain it?

Comment: @Android, It's very simple: _You can't disable or remove the warning._

Comment: Is there any way to send sms to self without costing money. just for testing purposes